# Unable to run migration executable against db in Azure Government Cloud resource

Tags: azure-devops, azure-gov

Our CI/CD build and release pipelines include a custom migrator executable that takes in a connection string and runs migrations against the database. Normally, since this runs in Azure DevOps, we only have to turn on the "Allow access to Azure service" option in the db firewall settings in Azure portal.

This is turned on for this new deployment, but it's not working. Is this something to do with Azure Government Cloud? This is a huge deal if I have to keep modifying the IP whitelist every time MS changes them. Is there a script available that will find the hosted agent's IP address and temp whitelist it on the firewall?

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible the "Allow access to Azure service" option only targets known services in Azure Public vs. Government. What type of database are you using?

Comment: It's an Azure SQL db in the same resource group.